# JUnit tests are not being detected

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, testing, junit

I am submitting a Hackerrank test. I have been asked to use my IDE to complete the tasks and then upload a zip folder. When I run the tests in my IDE, everything works fine however, when I upload the zip folder to Hackerrank and try to run the unit tests, they don't get detected. Instead, I get the following:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------< aspectcapital:software-development-test >---------------
[INFO] Building software-development-test Candidate-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.22.0/maven-surefire-plugin-2.22.0.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.22.0/maven-surefire-plugin-2.22.0.pom (5.0 kB at 15 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire/2.22.0/surefire-2.22.0.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire/2.22.0/surefire-2.22.0.pom (27 kB at 911 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/31/maven-parent-31.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/31/maven-parent-31.pom (43 kB at 2.3 MB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/19/apache-19.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/19/apache-19.pom (15 kB at 1.1 MB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.22.0/maven-surefire-plugin-2.22.0.jar
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.22.0/maven-surefire-plugin-2.22.0.jar (41 kB at 2.0 MB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.9.3/junit-jupiter-api-5.9.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/opentest4j/opentest4j/1.2.0/opentest4j-1.2.0.jar
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-commons/1.9.3/junit-platform-commons-1.9.3.jar
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/opentest4j/opentest4j/1.2.0/opentest4j-1.2.0.jar (7.7 kB at 219 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-commons/1.9.3/junit-platform-commons-1.9.3.jar (103 kB at 2.0 MB/s)
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.9.3/junit-jupiter-api-5.9.3.jar (208 kB at 3.7 MB/s)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ software-development-test ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /run-zlwe7bwOtCVcpjT54bRb/Solution/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ software-development-test ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ software-development-test ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /run-zlwe7bwOtCVcpjT54bRb/Solution/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ software-development-test ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /run-zlwe7bwOtCVcpjT54bRb/Solution/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) @ software-development-test ---
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/2.22.0/maven-surefire-common-2.22.0.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/2.22.0/maven-surefire-common-2.22.0.pom (11 kB at 874 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.5/maven-plugin-annotations-3.5.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.5/maven-plugin-annotations-3.5.pom (1.7 kB at 152 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools/3.5/maven-plugin-tools-3.5.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools/3.5/maven-plugin-tools-3.5.pom (16 kB at 1.2 MB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-api/2.22.0/surefire-api-2.22.0.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-api/2.22.0/surefire-api-2.22.0.pom (3.5 kB at 354 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-logger-api/2.22.0/surefire-logger-api-2.22.0.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-logger-api/2.22.0/surefire-logger-api-2.22.0.pom (2.0 kB at 98 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.22.0/surefire-booter-2.22.0.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.22.0/surefire-booter-2.22.0.pom (7.4 kB at 433 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-java/0.9.8/plexus-java-0.9.8.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-java/0.9.8/plexus-java-0.9.8.pom (2.4 kB at 102 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-languages/0.9.8/plexus-languages-0.9.8.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-languages/0.9.8/plexus-languages-0.9.8.pom (2.2 kB at 116 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/6.1.1/asm-6.1.1.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/6.1.1/asm-6.1.1.pom (2.9 kB at 294 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/ow2/1.5/ow2-1.5.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/ow2/1.5/ow2-1.5.pom (11 kB at 1.6 MB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/2.0-M7/qdox-2.0-M7.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/2.0-M7/qdox-2.0-M7.pom (16 kB at 1.4 MB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.22.0/surefire-booter-2.22.0.jar
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/2.22.0/maven-surefire-common-2.22.0.jar
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-logger-api/2.22.0/surefire-logger-api-2.22.0.jar
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-api/2.22.0/surefire-api-2.22.0.jar
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.5/maven-plugin-annotations-3.5.jar
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.5/maven-plugin-annotations-3.5.jar (14 kB at 227 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.15/plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-logger-api/2.22.0/surefire-logger-api-2.22.0.jar (13 kB at 148 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-api/2.22.0/surefire-api-2.22.0.jar (186 kB at 1.7 MB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/3.0/maven-reporting-api-3.0.jar
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/3.0/maven-reporting-api-3.0.jar (11 kB at 98 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-java/0.9.8/plexus-java-0.9.8.jar
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-java/0.9.8/plexus-java-0.9.8.jar (35 kB at 276 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/6.1.1/asm-6.1.1.jar
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.15/plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar (228 kB at 1.3 MB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/2.0-M7/qdox-2.0-M7.jar
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.22.0/surefire-booter-2.22.0.jar (273 kB at 1.5 MB/s)
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar (315 kB at 1.7 MB/s)
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/6.1.1/asm-6.1.1.jar (108 kB at 588 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/2.22.0/maven-surefire-common-2.22.0.jar (524 kB at 2.8 MB/s)
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/2.0-M7/qdox-2.0-M7.jar (315 kB at 1.5 MB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-junit4/2.22.0/surefire-junit4-2.22.0.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-junit4/2.22.0/surefire-junit4-2.22.0.pom (3.1 kB at 308 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-providers/2.22.0/surefire-providers-2.22.0.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-providers/2.22.0/surefire-providers-2.22.0.pom (2.5 kB at 276 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-junit4/2.22.0/surefire-junit4-2.22.0.jar
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-junit4/2.22.0/surefire-junit4-2.22.0.jar (85 kB at 6.0 MB/s)
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.715 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-12-09T01:15:02Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, it says I have no tests to run, which is not the case. Here is my `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>aspectcapital</groupId>
  <artifactId>software-development-test</artifactId>
  <version>Candidate-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Testing dependencies. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>aspectcapital.Main</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

And here is an example test class for reference:

```
package aspectcapital.question1;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

/** Question 1 usage - Please provide example usage of your map method here */
public class QuestionOneTest
{
    private final QuestionOne mQuestionOne = new QuestionOne();

    @Test
    void examplePlusOneUsingMapFunction()
    {
        List<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
        Function<Integer, Integer> plusOneFunction = num -> num + 1;

        assertEquals(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2,3,4)), mQuestionOne.map(plusOneFunction, numList));
    }

    @Test
    void multipleFunctionsApplied()
    {
        List<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
        Function<Integer, Integer> plusOneFunction = num -> num + 1;
        Function<Integer, Integer> doubleFunction = num -> num * 2;

        assertEquals(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4,6,8)), mQuestionOne.map(plusOneFunction.andThen(doubleFunction), numList));
    }
}
```

I have tried a lot of the other solutions that I have seen on here and elsewhere but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Based on your test class you are using JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5) import `org.junit.jupiter.*` but you have a dependency to JUnit 4? I suppose you want to use JUnit Jupiter so you can remove the dependency to JUnit 4...

Answer (score 0):

Make your test cases public.

```
package aspectcapital.question1;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
public class QuestionOneTest
{
    private final QuestionOne mQuestionOne = new QuestionOne();

    @Test
    public void examplePlusOneUsingMapFunction()
    {
        List<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
        Function<Integer, Integer> plusOneFunction = num -> num + 1;

        assertEquals(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2,3,4)), mQuestionOne.map(plusOneFunction, numList));
    }

    @Test
    public void multipleFunctionsApplied()
    {
        List<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
        Function<Integer, Integer> plusOneFunction = num -> num + 1;
        Function<Integer, Integer> doubleFunction = num -> num * 2;

        assertEquals(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4,6,8)), mQuestionOne.map(plusOneFunction.andThen(doubleFunction), numList));
    }
}
```

Comment: This made no difference unfortunately. Same issue happened

Comment: Making them public it not neccessary nor is the issue here. Since JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5) you don't need to make the public...

Answer (score 0):

To make running unig tests which are using [JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5)](https://junit.org/junit5/) you have to use [maven-surefire-plugin/maven-failsafe-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) (for integration tests) at least version 2.22.2 or higher.

That means you have to define all plugins you are using in your pom file. That is in general best practice to make sure you are using always the same versions.

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.soebes.youtube.maven.episodes</groupId>
  <artifactId>example-episode-2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>    
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.1</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-bom</artifactId>
        <version>3.24.2</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
      <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.11.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

Furthermore your unit tests with JUnit Jupiter(aka JUnit 5) don't need to be public. The test class as well as the test methods can be defined as "package local" which means no explicit access modifier like this:

```
class FirstTest {

  @Test
  void first_add() {
    First sum1 = new First(5);
    First sum2 = new First(2);

    assertThat(sum1.add(sum2)).isEqualTo(new First(7));
  }

  @Test
  void second_add() {
    First sum1 = new First(10);
    First sum2 = new First(2);

    assertThat(sum1.add(sum2)).isEqualTo(new First(12));
  }
}
```

More details can be found here: https://github.com/khmarbaise/youtube-videos/ or on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/@khmarbaise

If you need to run JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 test within the same project you have to make a different setup more details in https://github.com/khmarbaise/youtube-videos/tree/main/episode-3. I strongly recommend to use JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5) only.